# When we open pdf in iPhone then how to save this pdf in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, pdf

I am very new to iOS. I create `PDF` and load this `PDF` on `UIWebView`
now this time I want to save or download this `PDF` in iPhone when we tapped download button then all exits `PDF` supporter show like as open ibook ,open in chrome. This type of option show but when we tap any one then my application closed.

[image]

```
  -(void)show_Button
  {

    NSArray *docDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *docDirectory = [docDirectories objectAtIndex:0];

   NSString *filePAth = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];

   NSLog(@"filePath = %@", filePAth);
   NSURL *url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePAth];
   NSLog(@"url2 = %@", url2);

   UIDocumentInteractionController *docContr = [UIDocumentInteractionController
                                             interactionControllerWithURL:url2];
   docContr.delegate=self;
  [docContr presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
  }
```

so how to save or download this pdf in Iphone please  solve this problem....

Comment: You are getting the path from the directory and the file already exist there.Why resave it?

Comment: How to go there I mean to open pdf actually I get path but i can't find path where we  save pdf ....so how to save this in my app

Answer (score 0):

I hope this it will help you,
Saving the pdf into app

```
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: path]]; 
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);         
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pdfname.pdf"];      
NSError *writeError = nil;   
     [imageData writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&writeError];
           if (writeError) {
              NSLog(@"Error writing file: %@", writeError);    }
```

Getting the pdf from the NSDocument Directory

```
NSString *stringPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:&error];

for(int i=0;i<[filePathsArray count];i++)
{
    NSString *strFilePath = [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([[strFilePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"pdf"]) 
    {
        NSString *pdfPath = [[stringPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/"] stringByAppendingFormat:strFilePath];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath];
        if(data)
        {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            [arrayOfImages addObject:image];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simple use the belo two line:

```
NSData *myFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your_url"]]; 
[myFile writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"yourfilename.pdf"] atomically:YES];
```